# VHDL writing to file

Tags: file-io, vhdl

I have a simple task to do. I have a moudule hilbert which is unit under test. I just want to write "real_o" and "img" in a file on every rising edge of clock like

> 1   2
>
> 1   3
>
> 0  -2
>
> 0  -1
>
> 1   0
>
> 1   4

Where left column is real_o and right is img.

test bench code is

```
COMPONENT hilbert

PORT(

     clk : IN  std_logic;

     reset : IN  std_logic;

     x : IN  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

     real_o   : out STD_LOGIC;

     img : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)

    );

END COMPONENT;
```

**--Inputs**

```
signal clk : std_logic := '0';

   signal reset : std_logic := '0';

   signal x : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

**--Outputs**

```
   signal img : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

   signal real_o : std_logic;


BEGIN





-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)



uut: hilbert PORT MAP (

      clk => clk,

      reset => reset,

      x => x,

      real_o => real_o,

      img => img

    );
```

Can someone tell me steps to write real_o and img signals columnwise in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough for this site.  People will help you, but only if you have a specific problem that you are trying to solve.  "Can you tell me what steps to do whatever" is too vague.

I will link you to an example that I created for file IO in VHDL that might help you.  If you have any specific problems feel free to create a new post about them.

[VHDL Writing to File](http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-file-io.html)